# Why did Mark Twain write: There laid a man on the ground

Tags: grammar, past-tense

By and by I was close enough to have a look, and there laid a man on the ground.

I thought it would be correct to say:
There lies a man on the ground. (now)
There lay a man on the ground. (before)

If laid is used here as Past Tense, therefore the Present Tense is:
There lays a man on the ground.

How to understand this usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twain's use is non-standard, I suspect this is part of the conceit of the novel. It is presented as if it is a transcript of spoken English, and this kind of error is common in spoken English. In speech, many people use laid instead of lay as the past simple of lie: "He laid down and went to sleep."

There is a separate issue of the syntax.
This is a "locative" inversion.  English allows for the subject and verb to change places when a phrase indicating "place" is put at the front of the sentence:

> Jim sat on the chair (no inversion)

> On the chair sat Jim  (the subject has inverted with the verb)

Here the locative phrase is "There"

> A man laid there, on the ground (no inversion)

> There laid a man on the ground (inversion)